# How do I gain more exp when I have no Pokeballs and no Pokestops available

Tags: pokemon-go

I am in a very delicate situation. I am at level 4 in Pokemon go and I just need  200 more exp to level up, but  the  problem  is  that  I  have  no  more  pokeballs. Also, there  are  no  pokestops  available. What  do  I  do?

Comment: Go get more pokeballs.  If you've used all your pokestops, wait about five minutes, and they're good to go again, I think.

Comment: You have two options - 1. walk around and find some pokestops in your area 2. pay money and buy pokeballs from the store

Comment: @Frank I think you should rewrite your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 7):

The only ways to get more Pokeballs is either by going to Pokestops, which refresh every 5 minutes, or purchasing them in game with coins. Coins can be gained from controlling gyms, or buying them with real money.
You also get some by leveling up but not enough to maintain yourself.

Comment: There's one other way: you can level up. You might be able to do this by evolving some existing Pokemon, or hatching some eggs that you have, both of which earn you a fairly large amount of exp.

Comment: @Schism I edited that in at the last second but like I said you would never be able to maintain yourself with it. If you don't have any Pokestops near you to get Pokeballs then you wouldn't be able to hatch enough eggs to level up. And without Pokeballs you can't get enough stardust to keep evolving Pokemon for experience. 
You might be able to get a level up if you're close enough like the poster said they are, but that's about it.

Comment: Oh, I didn't see the edit before I posted my comment. Yep you're right, it's useful for a one-time boost but that's it.

Answer (score 0):

You can hatch eggs to receive about 200xp each, or give someone a gift, or buy pokeballs with real money from the pokeshop.